# httpwebrequest 401 response

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-401

I have a program written in VB.net that interacts with a data services hosted on IIS.  Authentication is handled through the users Active Directory credentials.  At one of my customer sites, on exactly one (out of about 100) of the customer's workstations, requests to the data service fail with status of 401.

Some additional relevant information: the production IIS installation is split into two nodes.  A load balancer directs traffic to the nodes.  Also, the exact same request made with Internet Explorer from workstation in question does not fail.

I suspect that something is stripping the user's credentials out of the requests when I make the request through the VB code, but I am stumped as to what that could be.

Here is the VB code that I use to make the request:

```
  Dim httpRequest As HttpWebRequest = Nothing
  Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = Nothing

  httpRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://server/xyzportal/portal.php")
  httpRequest.KeepAlive = False
  httpRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = True
  httpRequest.Method = "GET"
  httpRequest.ContentLength = 0
  httpRequest.Accept = "text/xml"
  httpRequest.Timeout = 3000000

  httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Additional information: here are the IIS log entries for a request that fails.  Notice the 2nd entry does not include the Windows user name:

```
2014-11-11 22:20:42 199.99.51.58 GET /xyzportal/portal.php - 80 - 199.99.50.128 - 401 2 5 0
2014-11-11 22:20:42 199.99.51.58 GET /xyzportal/portal.php - 80 - 199.99.50.128 - 401 1 2148074248 0
```

Contrast that to the IIS entries for a request from a working machine.  Notice the 2nd entry does include the Windows user name:

```
2014-11-11 22:56:40 199.99.51.58 GET /xyzportal/portal.php - 80 - 199.99.50.128 - 401 2 5 0 
2014-11-11 22:56:40 199.99.51.58 GET /xyzportal/portal.php - 80 MYDOMAIN\jreichert 199.99.50.128 - 200 0 0 93
```

The machine with the IP Address 199.99.50.128 is the load balancer.

I am logged in on the exact same domain and user on both machines.

Comment: I discovered if explicitly create credentials - Dim credentials As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential(user, pass) - then assign the credentials to the httpWebRequest.Credentials property the request succeeds.  I'm still baffled as to why this only occurs on one machine.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said but if you are using a proxy then you haven't told the HttpRequest to use the AD user credentials for the proxy and so you are getting a **401 Unauthorised** error, i.e. you are being refused access via the proxy. If so try this to explicitly tell it to...

```
HttpRequest.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

I had exactly the same problem and it's solved it.

Comment: This answer by itself isn't useful. Why would `DefaultCredentials` address the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This solution did not work in my case.  FWIW I don't think the request is being routed through a proxy:  no proxy is setup on the workstation in Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings.

Answer (score 0):

keepalive must be set to true.  Setting keepalive = true fixes my problem.  The following page explains the role of keepalive in the authentication handshake:

http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

I am still not sure why the request does not work on <1% of the workstations in my customer base when keepalive = false.  All I know is setting keepalive = true makes the request work on 100% of the workstations.

More info: keepalive must be set to true when the authentication protocol is Kerebos.  The request works if the authentication protocol is NTLM.  I don't know why Kerebos gets used on only the two workstations where the request does not work.